# jQuery deferred/promise works as expected only in debug mode

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a curious issue while implementing a dynamic search bar which aims to find values in a dynamic populated table.

Here's the guilty snipped code:

```
$('#myTable-searchInputBar').on('keyup', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.when(toggleTableVisibility()).then(function(){
        if($('.myTable-selected').attr('tab') != 'tuttiTab'){
            tabVisibility($('.myTable-tabInDiv[tab="tuttiTab"]'));
        }
        if(value.length > 2){
            $.when(findInArray($('.myTableRow'), isNaN(value) ? value.toLowerCase() : value)).then(toggleTableVisibility());
        }else{
            $.when(showAllRows()).then(toggleTableVisibility());
        }
    })
});
```

Down here are the three function recalled by the main function:

```
function toggleTableVisibility(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $('#loadingDiv').toggle();
    $('#tableContainer').toggle();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}

function findInArray(json, val) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(json).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('nonSelectedRow');
        $(this).find('.myTableCol:not(".nonSelectedCol")').each(function(){
            var text = isNaN($(this).text()) ? $(this).text().toLowerCase() : $(this).text();
            if(text.indexOf(val) != -1){
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('nonSelectedRow');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}

function showAllRows(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if($('.myTableRow.nonSelectedRow').length > 0){
        $('.myTableRow.nonSelectedRow').removeClass('nonSelectedRow');
    }
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the above code could be optimized and improve, but that's not the point of the question: what happens is that when i run it in debug, all steps are correctly followed and the expected behaviour is fully achieved. When I disable all the breakpoints and let the code flows as it would in a normal user navigation all that I see is that it seems to "freeze" 2/3 seconds (depends on how many elements are present in the given table) then it "unfreeze" with all the value filtered.
The function toggleTableVisibility() should hidden the table and show a loading gif with a spinning wheel.

Am I missing some basic point? 
As you could guess, i'm new in jQuery and javascript in general.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help / suggestion you all could give

PS 
I think the code is pretty self explanatory but if you need more comments about it i'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Why do you use promises? All your methods are simple and are voids

Comment: *"depends on how many elements"* ... how many rows and cells in table?

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst promises were the last attempt to have all the instructions executed one after another in a sequential way. I've tried also with .queue() and, before that, by simply calling methods one by one.

Comment: @charlietfl the table have always 41 columns, rows may vary from 21 to 4000+

Comment: 4000+ rows with that many columns is a lot of elements in page. Suggest you use an optimized table script. Also do some *"throttling"* in the `keyup`

Comment: @charlietfl i'll give a shot about throttling in the keyup but, as I stated in my question, it's not a performance issue: the search works as intended. With 41 columns x 4000 rows (each cell could contain text, numbers or both) it took 2-3 seconds to perform the substring research on all elements. 
My problem is that it doesn't show/hide those divs, it simply freeze for 2 seconds then shows all the subset elements filtered by the search string.
Thanks for your advice, BTW